# References for conceptual issues in Quantum Field Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations

I realize this question is very broad but may be I will still get a helpful answers. References and textbooks for the development of the technical and mathematical aspects of QFT abound. However, I never came across a source dealing with the conceptual issues of QFT. I am interested in stuff like,

- the meaning of Gauge symmetry,
- Spontaneous symmetry breaking,
- interpretation of renormalization group,
- etc.

Are there any reference that deals with these issues mainly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This answer contains some additional resources that may be useful. **Please note that answers which simply list resources but provide no details are strongly discouraged by [the site's policy on resource recommendation questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/are-resource-recommendations-allowed)**. This answer is left here to contain additional links that do not yet have commentary.

- B. Falkenburg, Particle Metaphysics, Springer, 2007.
- Also by T.Y.Cao (BTW, [NitinCR's suggestion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/15556/references-for-conceptual-issues-in-quantum-field-theory/15733#15733) is a compilation of articles by various authors from a number of points of view), Conceptual Developments of 20th Century Field Theories, Cambridge UP, 1997.
- S.Y.Auyang, How is Quantum Field Theory Possible, Oxford UP, 1995.
- Try the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry on QFT](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantum-field-theory/), which includes (not too) many citations to books and papers. For conceptual issues on Physics generally, this is one place to look.
- Look at Tom Banks' book Modern Quantum Field Theory: A Concise Introduction
- It's not a book, but it might be helpful:
  [The Conceptual Basis of Quantum Field Theory](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/basisqft.pdf) by Gerard 't Hooft. The file is [on his web page](http://www.phys.uu.nl/~thooft/lectures/basisqft.pdf).
- There is a book, edited by T.Y. Cao, a rather notable philosopher of science at Boston University, that might be of interest. The title is "Conceptual Foundations of Quantum Field Theory".
- A. Zee's "Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell" is also a very good reference.
- The series by E. Zeidler are really worth reading through.

Credit: Peter Morgan, and deleted answers by NitinCR, Curious George and Physicists.